# mysql - Determine if record exists with a left join query

Tags: mysql

I have a join query as such

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM procedures 
        LEFT JOIN doctors 
        ON procedures.ID = doctors.procedure_id";
```

with this join there can or cannot be a record in the doctors table. If there isnt I add the record through a form post. What I want to do is only display the records in the procedures table that do not have a related record in the doctors table so my screen does not list every record. I only care about the ones that do not have a related record in the doctors table.

I tried to add a

```
WHERE doctors.notes = ''
```

at the end of the query but since there is no record in the table it does not work. How can I determine if the record exists if possible with this join query. I could write a longer more clunkier query but trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`doctors.notes` would not be an empty string, as the data wouldn't exist. It would be `NULL`.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    procedures 
LEFT JOIN 
    doctors 
ON 
    procedures.ID = doctors.procedure_id
WHERE
    doctors.procedure_id IS NULL
```

Comment: dude thanks man, I even thought of trying that. I should have :)